Echo y from within python
I'm trying to import and use a module originally made as a standalone script.
Preferably without altering it, to keep tool commonality with the authors.
One function I'm using prompts for a y/n response, to which I want to always answer "y":
input("\nContinue? (y/n): ").lower()

What's the best way to automate this answer?

Please include a minimum example.

Well, you can do echo y | python script.py, but it would be better to replace that statement with answer = 'y'.

Does the module ask for any other keyboard input?

Preferably without altering it, to keep tool commonality with the authors. - it may be worth noting that this kind of isolated change is very well supported by version control tools.

Try replacing sys.stdin (the place where input reads it's data from) with something that always outputs y.
import io
import sys
one_hunderd_yesses = io.StringIO('y\n'*100)

original_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = one_hunderd_yesses

# Run the external module
print(input("\nContinue? (y/n): ")) # Outputs "y"

# When you are done, reset stdin
sys.stdin = original_stdin

Try this on ATO

Maybe set some parameter as debug. I can give you an example.
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
   args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   args.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', default=False)
   args = args.parse_args()
   ...
   # later in the code where the prompt is about to show
   while True:  # Or if you have something like answer=='Yes' just whatever
   ...
   answer = input('...').lower() if not args.debug else 'y'

This way if you are in debug mode the answer will always be 'y'.
EDIT:
On input() you evoke I/O event which awaits for some I/O actions. I am not sure you could force some input from within the same interpreter/running-code.
This could be covered from javascript maybe, event which awaits I/O request from script which is run by such JS. Or some observer. But vanilla Python is most likely not able to do such thing.
